# <command line>:1:1: error: macro names must be identifiers

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-make

I am new to Linux and makefiles. I have a makefile which generates .a files.
When I run the makefile, I get the following error. I have no idea from which part of the code, the error occurs.

```
[oracle@dyl02703app004 erm]# make -f erm_make_ida all
.... Compiling /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/obj/ermparseyac.c
cc  -g                         -DANSI -D -DTRACE_ON -DIDA_VERSION='"ISP-RG-V5.10.7GEN2A"' -DNO_MCP -DBUILDING_ERP  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/include -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/module_test  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/include  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/cfm/include    -c /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src/ermparseyac.c -o /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/obj/ermparseyac.o
<command line>:1:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
make: *** [/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/obj/ermparseyac.o] Error 1
```

Any suggestions...?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have a `-D` flag with no name. Look in your makefile to see what is causing it.

Comment: Similarly, I had a `-D` flag starting with `-`.