# Cmake and make, error compiling scribus

Tags: makefile, cmake, qmake

I'm finding always an error while trying to compile Scribus 1.5 svn. I tried with both Qt4 and Qt5 but the error doesn't seems to rely on them.

This is the cmake output:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/fabio/scribusinstall .. -DUSE_QT5=1 -DQT_PREFIX="/opt/qt5/bin"
-- Shared Library Flags: 
-- Scribus 1.5.0.svn will be built to install into /home/fabio/scribusinstall
-- Machine: x86_64-linux-gnu, void pointer size: 8
-- Found target X86
-- Found target X86_64
-- Building for target x86_64-linux-gnu
-- Using standard ApplicationDataDir. You can change it with -DAPPLICATION_DATA_DIR
-- ----- USE QT 5-----
-- ----- USE QT Widgets-----
-- ----- USE Qt5Gui -----
-- ----- USE QT 5 XML -----
-- ----- USE Qt5WebKit -----
-- ----- USE Qt5WebKitWidgets -----
-- ----- USE Qt5Network -----
-- ----- USE Qt5OpenGL -----
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so  
ZLIB Library Found OK
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so  
Using PNG Library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so
PNG Library Found OK
OSG found OK
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so  
JPEG Library Found OK
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so  
TIFF Library Found OK
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.3", required is "2") 
Python Library Found OK
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so (found version "2.4.8") 
-- FreeType2 Library Found OK
-- Looking for FT_Get_First_Char in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so
-- Looking for FT_Get_First_Char in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so - found
-- Looking for FT_Get_Next_Char in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so
-- Looking for FT_Get_Next_Char in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so - found
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- checking for one of the modules 'libcairo>=1.2.0;cairo>=1.2.0'
CAIRO Library Found OK
-- Found Cups: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so (found version "1.5.3") 
CUPS Library Found OK
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.7.8") 
LIBXML2 Library Found OK
LCMS ReleaseLibrary: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so
LCMS Debug Library: LCMS_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
LCMS Library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so
LCMS 2 ReleaseLibrary: LCMS2_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
LCMS 2 Debug Library: LCMS2_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
LCMS 2 Library: LCMS2_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
LCMS ReleaseLibrary: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so
LCMS Debug Library: LCMS_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
LCMS Library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so
LittleCMS Library Found OK
-- checking for one of the modules 'fontconfig'
FontConfig Found OK
-- Could NOT find HUNSPELL (missing:  HUNSPELL_LIBRARIES HUNSPELL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Hunspell or its developer libraries NOT found - Disabling support for spell checking
PoDoFo found OK
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
Boost Library Found OK
Building without GraphicksMagick (use -DWANT_GRAPHICSMAGICK=1 to enable)
-- checking for one of the modules 'libpoppler>=0.19.0;poppler>=0.19.0'
-- Found poppler
-- Found poppler libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so
-- Found poppler includes: /usr/include/poppler
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file endian.h
-- Looking for include file endian.h - found
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h - found
RPATH: lib/scribus/plugins/;
-- Qt5::CoreQt5::WidgetsQt5::GuiQt5::XmlQt5::WebKitQt5::WebKitWidgetsQt5::NetworkQt5::OpenGL/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
-- Building with Scripter 1
-- Source header files will be installed
-- /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/resources/translations/po
-- The following GUI languages will be installed: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir
```

then I do:

```
cd ..
make
Scanning dependencies of target scribus_pgf_lib
[  0%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf/Decoder.cpp:583:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
make[2]: *** [scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o] Errore 1
make[1]: *** [scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/all] Errore 2
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

It doesn't seem to be a dependency problem because I installed them with the apt-get build-dep command in Ubuntu Precise (Linux Mint 13). What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edited to add make VERBOSE=1

```
fabio@fabio-EasyNote-TS11HR ~/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir $ make VERBOSE=1/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810 -B/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/CMakeFiles /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
make -f scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/build.make scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
cd /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810 /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
make -f scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/build.make scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Building CXX object scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o
cd /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf && /usr/bin/c++   -DNDEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_LOCATION_LIB -DQT_SENSORS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUSE_QT5 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf -I/opt/qt5/include -I/opt/qt5/include/QtCore -I/opt/qt5/mkspecs/default -I/opt/qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt5/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt5/include/QtXml -I/opt/qt5/include/QtWebKit -I/opt/qt5/include/QtOpenGL -I/opt/qt5/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWebKitWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQuick -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQml -I/usr/include/qt5/QtPrintSupport -I/usr/include/qt5/QtLocation -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSensors -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810 -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus    -DSHAREDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/\" -DDOCDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/doc/scribus/\" -DICONDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/icons/\" -DSAMPLESDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/samples/\" -DSCRIPTSDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/scripts/\" -DTEMPLATEDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/templates/\" -DDESKTOPDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/applications/\" -DLIBDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/lib/scribus/\" -DPLUGINDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/lib/scribus/plugins/\" -D -D -DCOMPILE_SCRIBUS_MAIN_APP -o CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o -c /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf/Decoder.cpp
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf/Decoder.cpp:583:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
make[2]: *** [scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o] Errore 1
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
make[1]: *** [scribus/third_party/pgf/CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/all] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir"
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

Following there are the only two "-D" definitions found in the Makefile:

```
# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local


# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `make VERBOSE=1` please?

Comment: I asked also to Scribus community if they know which error could be happened but seems that for them there is no problem..

Comment: It should be reproducible following the instructions at:
http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Building_SVN_versions_with_CMake and 
http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Official:Compile_with_CMake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<command line>:1:1: error: macro names must be identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779872/command-line11-error-macro-names-must-be-identifiers)

Answer (score 2):

You can start from the error you get:

```
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
```

The `<command-line>:0:1` shows that the error does not come from the `.cpp` file but from the options passed to the compiler. Since you generated a `Makefile` and called it with make, it means that the generated `Makefile` is erratic.

Now, `error: macro names must be identifiers` probably means that the `Makefile` tried to create a macro that does not correspond to a proper preprocessing identifier with the option `-D`. For example, if you type:

```
g++ foobar.cpp -D1
```

You will get the exact same error since `1` is not a valid identifier (valid identifiers only contain letters, digits and underscores; the first character can not be a digit). I can't deduce more with just what you have, but what you can do is search your `Makefile` for an invalid `-D` option an try to find which part of the `CMakeLists.txt` could have generated this option.

The macro definition with `-D` is often defined from a cmake file with the following command `add_definitions`. For example, I could have passed my error-prone `-D1` option by adding this line to the cmake:

```
add_definitions(-D1)
```

Hope you will manage to track down the cause of your error.

**EDIT:** The error is in this giant line:

```
cd /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf && /usr/bin/c++   -DNDEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_LOCATION_LIB -DQT_SENSORS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUSE_QT5 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus/third_party/pgf -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf -I/opt/qt5/include -I/opt/qt5/include/QtCore -I/opt/qt5/mkspecs/default -I/opt/qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt5/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt5/include/QtXml -I/opt/qt5/include/QtWebKit -I/opt/qt5/include/QtOpenGL -I/opt/qt5/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWebKitWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQuick -I/usr/include/qt5/QtQml -I/usr/include/qt5/QtPrintSupport -I/usr/include/qt5/QtLocation -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSensors -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir/scribus -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810 -I/home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus    -DSHAREDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/\" -DDOCDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/doc/scribus/\" -DICONDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/icons/\" -DSAMPLESDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/samples/\" -DSCRIPTSDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/scripts/\" -DTEMPLATEDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/scribus/templates/\" -DDESKTOPDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/share/applications/\" -DLIBDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/lib/scribus/\" -DPLUGINDIR=\"/home/fabio/scribusinstall/lib/scribus/plugins/\" -D -D -DCOMPILE_SCRIBUS_MAIN_APP -o CMakeFiles/scribus_pgf_lib.dir/Decoder.cpp.o -c /home/fabio/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/scribus/third_party/pgf/Decoder.cpp
```

In the middle of the line, there are the options `-D -D` that trigger your actual error. Now, the problem will be to find what generated this command line and how to correct this :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try following your suggestions. I'll post the results as soon as I can.

Comment: I posted the only two -D definitions that I found, none of them appear to be invalid..

Comment: Thank you! Can this be caused by cmake or from some configuration file? I can't understand how this can happen because I downloaded the source from apt-get source, so it should be working since already compiled version exists.. Is it possible that the version of cmake that I am using is not working correctly?

Comment: I searched in many files but I really can't find where the -D prefix can come from.. Can you suggest me the most probable files which can make this? In the following comment there is my ls output:

Comment: fabio@fabio-EasyNote-TS11HR ~/ScribusSVN/scribus-trunk-1.5.0svn201304091810/builddir $ ls
CMakeCache.txt       cmake_uninstall.cmake  CPackSourceConfig.cmake  resources
CMakeFiles           config.h               doc                      scribus
cmake_install.cmake  CPackConfig.cmake      Makefile

Comment: @fcole90 I am sorry. I tried to find the most probable location, but I can't come up with better than "one of the cmake files". I bet some line somewhere adds a `-D` to the generated `Makefile` or calls a sbuscript that does so, but I can't say which. There may be a line with `add_definitions` that adds it in one of the subscripts, but I really can not be precise enough to help you more.

Comment: this question and answer is more than just a scribus issue. It is a gcc issue. Thanks for the answer.